# Give-credit vs. Thank-you comment

Tags: discussion, moderation

Karlis Olte commented on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18557503/343721) suggesting a better phrasing.

I replied somenthing like *Thank you, that's better, I updated my answer according to your suggestion*.

Later, some marshall activist deleted my comment as thank you comment. Technically he was right, but the reason to comment was to be polite to Karlis, give him the credit *"according to your suggestion"*. Otherwise he might think *Oh, he just leeched my comment, updated and ignored me.*

Of course it was thank you comment. But isn't such moderation too pedantic? I avoid irrelevant chats, but can I be human a little to leave one short comment?

I understand that larger communities need different approach in moderation. If SO is the case, then all the comments below the answer don't have any meaning anymore and should be deleted altogether, no?

The discussion should be how to approach such comments.

Comment: What about just up-voting such comments instead of replying?

Comment: One solution is to include the "thank you" in the answer itself:  "As per @xxx's suggestion . . .".  This is a more permanent attribution than a simple comment.

Comment: I typically leave 'courtesy' comments but delete them after a reasonable time when I think they have been read. Of course, I do the same with many of my 'this could be corrected' comments after the correction has been made.

Comment: @GordonLinoff readers are interested in the answer itself, not in who suggested what - your suggestion would make the answer much more tangled, it is quite long already. Maybe a little footnote *special thanks to...* but then some robo-reviewer might downvote the answer because of that. *Thank you* is blasphemy for them.

Comment: But also remember that the licensing requires attribution so those belong in the answer. Maybe as a footnote, to not make them tangled. Of course reacting to a suggestion probably does not fall under the license, I just mentioned it for completeness.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do that quite a lot (i.e. in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8486188/343721) I gave credit to four comentators). But *proper phrasing* seems to be too little contribution to be mentioned (since the topic is not a linguistic issue), yet it surely deserves at least a comment.

Comment: I wouldn't delete a comment like that, but Gordon's suggestion really is the way to go.

Comment: @Arc676 That's a brilliant suggestion, I ... hey, wait ...

Comment: `marshall activist` word of the day for me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with *leaving* such a comment, but it's inherently one of the more disposable types. A thank-you comment's best-by date is approximately 1 minute after being seen by the person it's addressed to, which is probably within a few hours of being left, most of the time.

Coincidentally, this means that effective, sensible comment moderation for that kind of comment will look a lot like moderation for terrible comments that we want to get rid of as fast as possible, so don't confuse "quickly deleted" for "offensive garbage you should be ashamed of posting".

Comment: This misses the OP's point, which is that thank-you comment was providing credit for the other comment's contribution to the post, and deleting them purges that attribution. You may think that such a minor contribution shouldn't be credited, and that the OP is being petty by wanting to provide credit, but thats a separate point.

Comment: @MarkAmery: The intended workflow of comments is to provide suggestions and have them incorporated, so once they're brought in, unless the suggestion is quite significant, they can be elided with just a record in the revision history remaining.

Comment: The OPs point is undermined by the transitory nature of comments. As has already been suggested, the right place to give credit is in the edit to the answer, because that is both more permanent and more visible.

Answer (score 26):

> But isn't such moderation too pedantic?

No, they were not. Comments have always been seen as things that can be removed at any time. If a comment is *important*, that just means in should be incorporated into the post.

> all the comments below the answer don't have any meaning anymore and should be deleted altogether, no?

Yes, pretty much. Though in practice, that doesn't happen that often (mostly due to moderators needing to be involved - it is a high burden).

Comment: Why are moderators involved, by the way. Why not just have the community moderate comments and have moderators only involved with the hairy stuff?

Comment: Things might well turn out that way.

Comment: I've heard before that it is because if comments are deleted, they're completly gone. But why is that an issue? Can a comment really have been that important that wrongfully deleting it would merit revisiting of the decision, or constitute a loss of value to the site.

Comment: @Magisch - we don't have good quality controls for comments. Just giving everyone (or even a large subset of people) the power will result in abuse (people deleting comments because they don't like them, the other person keeps posting new ones is just one such example) - we really don't want comment wars.

Comment: In that case I'd like to put flag on group of comments to be deleted altogether. It is confusing to flag comments one by one resulting in only some of them removed.

Comment: Why not then a comment review queue for flags on comments. Say 3 people need to agree to delete. Like the other queues. Maybe available for users of 2k and up, or 1k and up?

Comment: @Magisch Because of robo-reviewers.

Comment: @Daedalus by that logic you would need to remove all review queues, because robo-reviewers are everywhere.

Comment: @Magisch Not quite.  It'd simply be making one problem worse; that's the point I'm attempting to convey.

Comment: Comments aren't any more completely gone than any other content on the network -- it's just only moderators can see them and I think if we give regular users the ability to *delete* comments, they'd also need the ability to *undelete* them -- which means potentially seeing a whole lot of crap.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, thanking `Karlis` should be done in the answer rather than the comments? To me this is awkward -- to care about both comment and answer posterity. People want to thank/credit people sometimes for a suggestion, e.g., and to me it seems worse to put it in the answer rather than the comment.

Comment: @Ike - thanking `Karlis` should be done via upvote. Not in comments/answers.

Comment: The awkward part there for me is that an up-vote is anonymous. The author of the answer might want to specifically cite the person making the suggestion to make it clear where the information was obtained. :-(

Comment: If by *robo-reviewers* you mean automatic behavior, then, perharps, I could comment *Indeed, that's better...* instead of *Thank you, that's better...*? Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Ike well, when you get revenge upvoting, the script reverses them and you end up with less reputation than if it didn't happened, you will know to just being another anonymous supporter. (BTW, there's a bounty reason exactly for that kind of sentiment)

Comment: @Braiam Apologies, I didn't quite follow what you were trying to tell me there with respect to "revenge upvoting" and what you meant by "sentiment" here -- just the yearning to give credit to the person who made the suggestion?

Comment: Is revenge upvoting like, if person A has an answer, person B has an answer, person B suggests improvements to person A, person A thanks person B, and people end up up-voting person B's answer because person A thanked him?

Comment: @Ike you remember "serial up/downvoting"? Well, if you tell them you upvoted them, they may "thank" you by upvoting all your posts (I remember there was a case of that). And "just the yearning to give credit to the person", don't know if it's related to the sentence before, but here's the bounty:  **Reward existing answer** One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty. You can use that instead of comments.

Comment: @Braiam Oh I see. But I'm often thinking of cases where the person who suggested improvements to our answers may not even have an answer of their own -- that's typically more common to me at least than for someone already with an answer to suggest improvements to my posts. They're often random wanderers who pass by, suggest an improvement to an inaccuracy I made, and I want to thank them for it in a way that other people can see so that they know where I got the information.

Comment: @Braiam Or not even so much in terms of "thanks" -- to me it's just about citation -- thanks is a nicety, but it's mostly about just giving credit where it's due, to cite our sources. Any kind of anonymity here kind of loses its point -- otherwise a plagiarist could say he "cited the author/info anonymously with an up-vote" if accused of leeching info. To me the sole difference between a plagiarist and someone who uses references comes down to explicit acknowledgement of where the info came from.

Comment: @JanTuroň: *"In that case I'd like to put flag on group of comments to be deleted altogether."* The guidance for that situation is to flag the answer/question with a "needs moderator" flag saying which comments to be removed. There was a meta question about that fairly recently; that was the upshot.

Comment: @Ike well, I see it like this: I could be reading your thanks comment, or fixing other post, voting, answering, dealing with the queues, etc. Simply stated, your comment makes me lose time I could use for other stuff which is more productive. The benefit is always on the marginals!

Comment: @Braiam That's generally true with credits/citations in general -- like when I watch a movie, I'm not interested in credits -- it's kind of a waste of my time. Same with some preface in a book, a bibliography in a paper. It's not for the audience, it's for proper credit/acknowledgement. Probably the best place is maybe to put it in the answers, like as a footnote -- this way it's out of the way and discreet.

Comment: @Braiam For total site posterity maybe everything should be anonymous, even the answers and questions -- we can't see who authored anything, only the information inside. That would put total emphasis on the info and no emphasis at all on where it came from. Then things like crediting where the information came from no longer becomes an issue. But once we do anything which has our name on it, then I think it's equally essential to cite the source.

Answer (score 18):

I think it is okay to leave such comments. Especially if you have more to say than just “thank you”, such as “thank you, that is indeed correct because *X*”. Most of the time, you should be able to add such a delta.

Another legitimate reason to post such a comment is that the person who left the first comment might have been withholding their up-vote for until the suggested improvement is incorporated and by answering to the comment, you can ping them. Personally, I wouldn't up-vote an otherwise good answer if it had a major error in it and by being notified that the error is now corrected, I can re-consider my voting so I'd kind of expect it. Of course, once I have been notified, there isn't much value in the comment any more and it can be garbage collected safely. (For more severe errors, you may substitute “not voted yet” with “down-voted” and “up-vote” with “withdraw the down-vote”.)

A protocol that I have seen used a lot and that I try to follow is this.

1. Alice posts an answer.
2. Bob leaves a comment suggesting an improvement to the answer.
3. Alice agrees with the comment, up-votes it, updates her answer and replies to the comment, pinging and thanking Bob.
4. Bob sees the updated answer, possibly up-votes it, and deletes his now-obsolete comment.
5. Alice sees that her “thank you” comment is now dangling and deletes it as well.

This way, all necessary communication gets across and yet the site is kept tidy and moderators are not distracted from more important tasks than deleting obsolete comments.

If a moderator does delete the “thank you” comment, I think they should delete the original comment that suggested the edit as well, provided that the edit was fully incorporated and therefore the comment doesn't add much value any more.

Comment: In that case the Karlis' suggestion should be deleted prior to my acknowledgement. If robo-reviewers just literally follow "no thank you comment", maybe there could be a note like "flag the contents, too". But if it is up to moderators to handle this, they should be sensitive enough to take care of the contents anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I too feel that giving credit where credit is due is really important. So whenever people make suggestions to update my answer, I leave them a thankyou comment. And then after a day or so, I go back and delete my thankyou comment. (The logic being that the user must have gotten my comment by now and deleting it so it doesn't become noise in the system)

Answer (score 6):

I am usually the first person to point out "what the site is for" and discourage misuse of features... but in this case I disagree with the established guidelines.

Upvoting comments is fine - and it's always nice be acknowledged anonymously - but there's value in knowing that the person whose answer you are addressing *specifically* appreciates your comment. It encourages positivity in the community and nurtures a culture of constructive criticism, which, in my opinion, is more valuable than cleaning up a small amount of 'noise' or enforcing the 'purpose' of the feature.

There's a very important distinction between knowing that someone likes your comment and knowing that the person you addressed appreciates your feedback (not to mention simple courtesy, which is something to be cherished in Internet communities).

Ultimately a simple "thanks for your comment" - while superfluous from a content perspective - will foster continued quality contributions from positive users.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is a collation of good answers.

A good answer contains as little noise as possible.

Comments are for ephemeral suggestions/additions - but a little more substantive than a suggested edit. Edits shouldn't alter the original intent, where a comment can suggest something that could/should be included.

If it's more substantive, and suggests extra content of some kind, then attribution is appropriate*. Worth including as reference, rather than in the main text.

More than this is unnecessary and redundant - if they were particularly bothered about getting rep/votes/etc. then they could have contributed an answer rather than a comment.

* as suggested by someuser.

Answer (score 2):

Like others, I find it difficult to *not* express gratitude for a helpful answer or comment. If I don't have anything informative or constructive to say in addition to "thank you" when replying to a comment, I simply upvote the helpful comment. It's subtle as there's nothing to indicate to the commentator that it was me who upvoted their comment but they'll know that *somebody* acknowledged their comment (and may draw the conclusion that it was me).

Often, I revisit a question or answer and delete any comments that have already been read by the person they're addressed to.

Answer (score 2):

> some marshall activist deleted my comment as thank you comment

What makes you believe that the "marshall activist" was not the person to whom the comment was directed? I.e. perhaps the person you thanked saw the comment, and having seen it deemed it no longer relevant to the post and flagged it for a moderator to remove?

As already explained in other answers, comments are ephemeral. That many are left that arguably should be deleted as no longer useful, does not mean that you should expect any comment to outlive its usefulness. If you want a more permanent way to cite authorship, you should do that in your post. There, you can use the extraneous verbiage "thank you" if you like (extraneous, because it's "chatty" and could have been expressed in a comment instead), or just provide a regular citation (e.g. "suggestion provided by ").

For better or worse, there's no way for you to know why a comment was deleted, not without asking here for that information and having a moderator go back and look. Regular users don't have access to comments at all after they are deleted, never mind metadata like who flagged or deleted the comment. It is entirely possible that your message was conveyed to the intended recipient as you'd hoped, and that having done its job, the comment was no longer needed and deleted for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

> Later, some marshall activist deleted my comment as thank you comment. Technically he was right, but the reason to comment was to be polite to Karlis, give him the credit "according to your suggestion". Otherwise he might think Oh, he just leeched my comment, updated and ignored me.

> The discussion should be how to approach such comments.

Here's are other routes that exist besides writing a "thanks, edited" comment:

1. Comment to Karlis asking them to edit that info into your post and then delete their comment.

   The nice thing about this option is that the edit history will actually show that Karlis really did say that (instead of you saying that they said that). But the downside is that it takes more coordination to clean up the comments that are then no longer needed (Karlis', and the one you added asking them to edit your post).
2. Edit to inline Karlis' comment into your post as a quote with quote formatting, and link to their user profile page. Then flag their comment as "No Longer Needed".
3. Edit to incorporate Karlis' contribution into your post in your own words, and credit them by linking to their user profile page. Then flag their comment as "No Longer Needed".
4. Edit to incorporate Karlis' contribution into your post in summarized form, and credit them by linking to their comment.

   This option is not really risky, but it is *slightly* more risky than the others, since the comment being linked-to still has a non-zero possibility of being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> some marshall activist deleted my comment

I think that statement alone shows that even after gaining 10K of reputation, you stil may not fully understand this site.

Stack Overflow is not a forum, nor a social network. One-on-one communication is discouraged for a wide variety of reasons.

Comments have always been and will always be meant to be temporary in nature. They're to address problems or unclarity with the post they're posted under.

Do understand that we're here to together build a collection of high-quality questions and answers. Comments just add noise to that. Comments, when relevant and correct, are to be integrated into the post. If you see a comment pointing out a mistake in an (older than a few hours) answer, don't upvote the comment, but edit the answer to include the content from the comment instead (as long as it doesn't change the meaning of the answer, and so on).

Anyway, back to "thanks": that is noise, and not more than that. Just upvote a helpful comment, and let the poster assume the vote was yours.

Comment: Even with 30k+ rep I still mostly disagree with your answer. While of course SO is not a social network (...well actually it might become one, thanks to the [sarcastic]great[/sarcastic] idea of "teams"...), _people are not bots_ and we should be able to act as humans, i.e. by saying thanks, especially when it could add some background information for future readers (i.e. not just "thanks", but "thanks, indeed you're right because...").

Comment: I learned not to have assumptions sometimes around 5k rep. I don't believe rep has any relevance with proffesionality, there are many 1k rep users much smarter than me. Rep measures SO compliance and maybe sometimes influence. Meta SO is more philosofical, there is no "right" answer here, consensus is what matters and your opinion has its rightful place, albeit it contradicts mine. I respect it as one of many possible attitudes, no less, no more.

Comment: *"I think that statement alone shows that even after gaining 10K of reputation, you stil may not fully understand this site."*  It's an obvious riposte, but it's possible that with 62k reputation, you do not understand the site.  Starting from basics, (1) like many others, it's a "prosumption" dotcom startup, where the aim is to make US Dollars by building it up and then either selling it or having an IPO. That's all it is and all it will ever be.  (2) presently, the "prosumption" model works and is making money for the site via advertising dollars. (3) within the "prosumption" model,

Comment: , certain "social norms" are current. (Such as "don't leave thank yous" or "comments can be deleted" or "the site is about programming questions".)  (4) these "social norms" (so to speak) can change at any time.  The sole and only ultimate arbiter is whether it Makes Money (in terms of item (1)).  If, as it happens, getting rid of the prosumption model and doing something else makes more money, that will happen.  If, and this happens all the time, the "social norms" of the prosumption model (what you apparently see as cast in stone) change, they'll just change.

Comment: @ken2k all I meant by that is that OP should have been expected to know that "thanks" comments are seen as noise and thus removed when flagged, so there is no use calling the mod that did so a "marshall activist". It does not sound very nice to a volunteer who is following the rules. To me this sounds like a _" We are not allowed to be nice! "_ complaint, which is simply not true.

Comment: @JoeBlow sure, but the current rules are, well, current. This is a discussion question, and I've explained my stance. Just vote for (dis)agreement. I'm also not saying you shouldn't _post_ such comments, but if you do, you'll have to accept they can be deleted to clean up a Q&A.

Comment: Quite right, CodeC.